# Kubernetes Statefulset Downscaling

Tags: kubernetes, solr, solrcloud, hpa

Currently I am running a solr cluster on Kubernetes as a statefulset. My solr cluster has 39 pods running in it. I am running a single pod on a single physical node. My solr cluster has just 1 collection divived into 3 shards, each shard has 13 nodes (or pods) running in it and out of those 13 nodes (or pods), 3 are TLOG replicas and 10 are PULL replicas.

The problem that I want to disucss is - I want to *autoscale my solr cluster*. On the basis of some condition I want to downscale my PULL replica nodes (or pods) to minimum, so that unnecessary  consumption can be reduced. Now I know I can use HPA in Kuberntes to autoscale, but while downscaling I don't want to stop my TLOG nodes (or pods). Similarly, while scaling up I want to just add PULL replicas to my cluster.

Can anyone please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can have different deployments for each one of the pod types, e.g one Deployment for TLOG pods and another one for PULL pods. Then you can define a fixed number of replicas for the TLOG pods and an HPA for the PULL pods. This will allow for adding / removing PULL pods only, without any impact on the TLOG pods.